# Generate uniform pseudo-random numbers in a closed interval

Tags: random, fortran

What's the best way to generate pseudo-random numbers in the closed interval [0,1] instead of the usual [0,1)? One idea I've came up with is to reject values in (1/2,1), then double the number. I wonder if there is a better method.

```
real x
do
   call random_number(x)
   if (x <= 0.5) exit
end do
x = 2*x
print *, x
end
```

The most important requirement is that the algorithm should not make a worse distribution (in terms of uniformity and correlation) than that generated by `random_number()`. Also I'd favour simplicity. A wrapper around `random_number()` would be perfectly good, I'm not looking to implement a whole new generator.

---

As @francescalus points out in the comments, with the algorithm above lots of numbers in [0,1] will have zero probability of appearing. The following code implements a slightly different approach: the interval is enlarged a bit, then values in excess of 1 are cut out. It should behave better in that aspect.

```
real x
do
   call random_number(x)
   x = x*(1 + 1e-6)
   if (x <= 1.) exit
end do
print *, x
end
```

Comment: "Best" will be too broad, so perhaps you can explain what properties you require in this new distribution.  For example, in the case of the question, lots of numbers in the interval [0,1] now have zero probability of appearing.

Comment: @francescalus The most important requirement is that it should not "ruin" the distribution generated by `random_number()`. I'm not looking to implement a whole new generator, just something to wrap `random_number()` in. I'd like it to be concise. Judging by the first requirement, the second algorithm I've added should be better, if I understood the problem with the first one correctly.

Comment: Be careful what you wish for. `random_number` generates a uniform random distribution. That means, the probability that you pick a number between `x` and `x+dx` is `p(x)dx = { dx for 0<=x<1; 0 otherwise }`. That said, `x` equal to one makes no sense!.

Comment: @kvantour what I'm looking for is a procedure that generates a uniform distribution such that p(x)dx = {dx for 0 ≤ x ≤ 1; 0 otherwise}. Doesn't it make sense?

Comment: What probability does p(x)dx represent in your case? A uniform distribution means that if you generate random numbers and put them in buckets, the buckets should fill at the same pace. Assume you have a random number generator that generates 4 numbers randomly (0,0.25,0.5,0.75) and you have two buckets. One bucket collecting all numbers from [0,0.5[ and the other one [0.5,1[. With these 4 random numbers, you will fill the buckets evenly (2 numbers fit in each bucket).

Comment: Well, the probability that I pick a number between x and x+dx. Are you hinting that now if I take x = 1 there's no place for adding dx?

Comment: Now Imagine, you want the number one inclusive, so you generate your five numbers (0,0.25,0.5,0.75,1), and you fill again your two buckets. Now you have all of a sudden 3 numbers in the second bucket. This is not uniform anymore because you have a single number more in the last bucket (if you expand it to  [0.5,1]) This is a very simplified picture, but it gives you the idea why you should exclude the number one because of the way you fill the buckets (i.e. dx)

Comment: @ArchStanton _Are you hinting that now if I take x = 1 there's no place for adding dx?_ Yes, where are you going to put it, in which bin? Where does it belong? If you put it in the bin from [1,1+dx[, you will only have a single number in that bin as you will never generate any other number that fits in the bin of size `dx`. While all other bins have many more numbers.

Comment: I see, but what if an algorithm requires me to pick numbers from a closed interval, as in the [Box-Muller transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box%E2%80%93Muller_transform#Polar_form)?

Comment: @ArchStanton The wiki page mentions random numbers generated according to U(0,1), this does not mean that 1 has to be included. I also think the page is a bit messy with the limits. If you look in numerical recipes it is nicely explained. In short, you can use `random_number` for the Box-Muller transform without any problem. You will have a very nice Gaussian distribution.

Comment: The cumulative distribution functions of the 4 uniform distributions U((0,1)), U([0,1)), U((0,1]) and U([0,1]) are *identical*, so you are worried about something which is virtually nothing.

Comment: @JohnColeman Getting comments like yours and kvantour's is one of the reasons I've asked this question :-)

Comment: I sencond @JohnColeman 's comment: any skew you could cause on the distribution (and additional computation) is not worth for a correction of the order of 5e-20 (assuming double precision) that is including one element in the domain.

Comment: I believe this question is actually a combination of two questions: (1) _The OP would like to implement Box-Muller, can he use Fortran's `random_number` as it only generates random numbers in the half-open interval [0,1) and the math states he needs U(0,1) with 1 included._ and (2) _Why is `1` not included in a real pseudo-random number generator for a uniform distribution U(0,1)? Does it make sense to include it?_

Comment: @kvantour Why (0...1) in Box-Muller? For quite some time folks when face U(0,1) RNG in [0...1) interval, just substitute U1/U2 in formulas with 1.0-U1, and all works well. What's wrong with using  (0...1] U(0,1) in Box-Muller? Updated my answer

Comment: @kvantour It wouldn't *hurt* to include 1 (at the cost of excluding some other representable real in [0,1) ), but any code that made explicit use of its inclusion (e.g. by explicitly testing for equality with 1) is probably bad code (IMHO).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about swapping x and 1-x? Sorry, my Fortran is rusty

```
real function RNG()
real ::    x
logical, save :: swap = .TRUE.

call random_number(x)
if (swap .EQV. .TRUE.)
    RNG = x
    swap = .FALSE.
else
    RNG = 1.0 - x
    swap = .TRUE.
end if

end
```

And if you want to use Box-Muller, use 1-U everywhere and it should work

```
z0 = sqrt(-2.0*log(1.0-U1))*sin(TWOPI*U2)
z1 = sqrt(-2.0*log(1.0-U1))*cos(TWOPI*U2)
```

same for rejection version of Box-Muller

Comment: This approach is just swapping the problem from the half-open interval [0,1) to the half-open interval (0,1]. The OP requests the closed interval [0,1]

Comment: @kvantour no, sometimes when 0 is sampled it will return 0, and sometimes when 0 is sampled it will return 1, so total interval for this method would be [0...1]

Comment: Ah, yes you are correct, but then the numbers 0 and 1 are sampled at half the probability of all the other numbers which will skew your binning (extremely slightly)

Comment: @kvantour that is correct, we're trading half of our zeros for ones

Comment: @kvantour Thank you, this is known thing in C++ when Standard says we will have dozen RNGs but all of them would be in [0...1) interval. You're right wrt `1.0D0-U1`, I apologize for my Fortran skllls being out of shape

Comment: Nice catch for the Box-Muller! You need indeed `1.0-U1` otherwise you could have a problem with the logarithm when you hit ZERO.